# How to get created date of file from document directory in iOS?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, nsdate, nsfilemanager

Yes i would like to get the created date of file from document directory in iOS.

It's like `NOTES` App from iOS.

In Notes App , there is a date that created and modified of file.

I also want to get date like that.

How can i do that?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: See `NSFileManager attributesOfItemAtPath:error:`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
NSError* error = nil;
NSDictionary  *file_info = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath: your_path error:&error];
NSDate *modified = file_info[NSFileModificationDate];
NSDate *created = file_info[NSFileCreationDate];
```

Comment: Why, why, why, for the love of Xcode do you create and pass an NSError parameter and then not check the return value from the method or handle any possible errors.

Comment: I left that as an exercise for the developer. Even if something goes wrong, the worst that will happen is he'll get nil values in modified and created. He asked about how to get the modified and created dates, not how to handle NSErrors :)

Comment: Then just pass a NULL for that parameter. You just know that this is going to be copied and pasted straight in.

Comment: Thanks for the info, it's not the job of the community to force well written code. If thats copied and pasted that's their issue. Keeping answers straight and to the point is very helpful. Adding the NSError without the correct error handling was a great way to remind me to handle the errors. Again, thanks for the helpful info.